# cline issue in drawing horizontal lines in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I am trying to draw a horizontal line for cells 2 to 3 and then for cell 5 in a table using `\\ \cline{2-3,5}`. But it does not work for me. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this in LaTeX `tabular` environment.

```
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Traffic} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Training} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Test}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Normal} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{67343} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{9711} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{Anomaly}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{DoS} & 45927 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{52000}} & 7458 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{10000}}\\  
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & U2R & 52 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 67 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & R2L & 995 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 2887 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}\\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & Probe & 11656 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}& 2421 &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} \\ 
\hline
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you using a `tabularx`? If not (or if not necessary for your question), delete this tag from your question. Please show us, where you have found that command with comma in it. Never seen it but I do not want to say, it does not exist for some package. the normal approach in my eyes would be to do `\\\cline{2-3}\cline{5-5}`

Comment: Thanks @LaRiFaRi . \cline{2-3}\cline{5-5} worked. I just intuitively put that which did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The command you are using does not support a comma separated list of parameters. It should be `\\\cline{2-3}\cline{5-5}` instead.

Below a recommendation on how to write the table for better readability and less coding. It also shows how to use the single column line but here with `booktabs`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Traffic & Training & Test\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    Normal & $67343$ & $9711$ \\
    \midrule
    Anomaly \specialcell{l}{DoS\\U2R\\R2L\\Probe} & \specialcell{S[table-format=5.0]}{45927\\52\\995\\11656}  \num{52000} & \specialcell{S[table-format=4.0]}{7458\\67\\2887\\2421}  \num{10000} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]